# Text not appearing in circle D3

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I am trying to center text inside of circles that are connected by arcs. I have seen other StackOverflow answers but none of them have solved my problem. I know to wrap each circle element in a g element and then append the text which is what I'm doing below. If anyone could help me with this that would be greatly appreciated.

```
let svg = d3.select("body").append('svg').attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + width + ' ' + boxHeight);
    let nodes: any = [[width / 2, boxHeight / 1.5], [width / 4, boxHeight / 3], [width / 1.5, boxHeight / 3]];
    let g = svg.append('g')
    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      g
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', nodes[i][0])
        .attr('cy', nodes[i][1])
        .attr('r', 40).style('stroke', 'green')
        .style('fill', 'none')
      g.append('text').attr('fill', 'black').text('Hello')
    }

    let links: any = [];
    // Link from the first node to the second
    links.push(
      d3.linkHorizontal()({
        source: nodes[0],
        target: nodes[1]
      })
    );

    // Link from the first node to the third
    links.push(
      d3.linkHorizontal()({
        source: nodes[0],
        target: nodes[2]
      })
    );

    // Append the links to the svg element
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      svg
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', links[i])
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .attr('fill', 'none');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You position the circles,

```
g.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', nodes[i][0])
  .attr('cy', nodes[i][1])
```

but not the text,

```
g.append('text').attr('fill', 'black').text('Hello')
```

so it likely appears at the top left of the screen (the text baseline is at 0, so you may see parts of letters that drop below the baseline.

Instead, you could position the g. Then append child text, circles:

```
 let node = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", d=>"translate("+d+")");

 node.append("circle") 
    .attr('r', 40).style('stroke', 'green')
    .style('fill', 'none')

 node.append("text") 
    .text("Hello")
    .style("text-anchor","middle")
    .style("dominant-baseline","middle");
```

eg:

```js
let g = d3.select("body").append("svg").append("g");
 
let nodes = [[100,100],[200,100]]
 
 
let node = g.selectAll(null)
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", d=>"translate("+d+")");

node.append("circle") 
        .attr('r', 40).style('stroke', 'green')
        .style('fill', 'none')

node.append("text") 
        .text("Hello")
        .style("text-anchor","middle")
        .style("dominant-baseline","middle");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise, you could position the text with the same x,y values as the cx/cy values of the circle and use text-anchor and dominant baseline attributes to center the text on that value:

```js
let g = d3.select("body").append("svg").append("g");
 
let nodes = [[100,100],[200,100]]
 
 
let node = g.selectAll(null)
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("g")

node.append("circle") 
        .attr('r', 40).style('stroke', 'green')
        .style('fill', 'none')
        .attr("cx", d=>d[0])
        .attr("cy", d=>d[1]);

node.append("text") 
        .text("Hello")
        .style("text-anchor","middle")
        .style("dominant-baseline","middle")
        .attr("x", d=>d[0])
        .attr("y", d=>d[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```